# Airport Time Capsule US power cord in Europe?

Tags: airport, time-capsule, power

I have a US power cord for my AirPort Time Capsule (802.11ac 2TB), and I want to use it in Europe (specifically Norway). The power outlets here deliver 220V rather than the 120V a US power outlet delivers. Will a simple plug adapter be enough, or will that fry my AirPort? That is, can the AirPort Time Capsule sold in the US handle 220V as well as 120V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember reading the tech specs for Timecapsule some time ago and it is specified it has a range of 100V to 240V. So it should be fine.

> *AirPort Time Capsule 802.11ac - Technical Specifications*
>
> **Electrical and Environmental Requirements**
>
> - 100-240V AC, 50-60Hz; input current: 1.5 amp

You can check this, too.

Here is a [link to the Apple TimeCapsule Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP679?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) - please also check if this is your version of Timecapsule.

Have a good trip!

Comment: Here is a [search query for older Airport TC Specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&q=airport%20time%20capsule%20power&product=&doctype=SPECIFICATIONS&currentPage=1&includeArchived=false&locale=en_US&src=support_searchbox_main&type=suggested)...

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Support Technical Specifications pages, it appears that Time Capsules (2nd gen, 3rd gen, 4th gen, 802.11ac) all show as capable of accepting voltages between 100V - 240V, AC, 50-60 Hz. So a simple outlet adaptor should work OK for these models.

You did not specify which version you had, so please check the specifications for your particular model.

Edit to add: It may be prudent to set up your Time Capsule with the region set to Norway as there are some slight differences between USA and EU WiFi channels. Using Airport Utility, access the Wireless Options and make sure these suit your local arrangements.

Comment: Updated my question with additional specs. 

Can you provide a link? All I could find on Apple's site were discussion posts.